# Trying to find an efficient algorithm for a problem involving primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-complexity

I encountered this problem while I was programming and trying to write an algorithm for a data structure and thought that maybe there was a dynamic programming approach that could solve this. I am not entirely sure if this is more of a math problem or a computer science one.

Problem: Assume that we have a positive integer $z$ and a list of primes in ascending order:

$$p_1 \leq p_2 \leq \cdots \leq  p_i \leq p_{i+1} \leq \cdots \leq p_n$$
(where primes can repeat). The primes satisfy the following properties:

a)  no $p_j$ is greater than $z$

b) $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n > z$

The goal is to find an algorithm that finds a sublist $p_{a_1}, \ldots, p_{a_k}$ of primes from the list $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ that satisfies two conditions:

1. $p_{a_1}p_{a_2} \cdots p_{a_k} > z$
2. the product $p_{a_1} p_{a_2} \cdots p_{a_k}$ is the minimal possible of all sublists that satisfy condition 1.

[In other words, we want to find a sublist whose product is greater than $z$ and also require that the sublist's product is as close to $z$ as possible]

My main question is whether there is an algorithm that is efficient(polynomial time?). The brute force solution I found was to write down a list of all possible sublists with product greater than $z$ and this list will be finite and then just take the minimum element, but this algorithm would be O($2^n$) since enumerating all possible sublists would give $2^n$ possibilities since you either include or exclude a $p_i$.

A note on why I made the three assumptions above:

a)- this is an assumption because such a $p_j$ could never be used in a minimal list that satisfies condition 2, so we just ignore them if they were in our list.

b)- this is an an assumption because I need this condition in my code.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain how the multiset of primes gets defined for $z$.  Your justification for assumption (c) will not always hold (consider primes $2\lt 3 = 3 \lt 5$ and target $z=8$).  Search is probably unavoidable.  Taking logarithms lets us convert to a variant of Subset Sum problems.

Comment: Upon reading this, I think that excluding assumption (c) does seem right, I think the reasoning for me adding it was misguided, so I will update the question without assumption (c). Also, I am getting the set of primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ from the prime decomposition from some number greater than $z$, so they really can be anything that fits condition (b) and then you can essentially just throw out all the primes that are bigger than $z$ like I mentioned above since they cannot be a part of the solution.

Comment: I will try thinking about it using logarithms and a subset sum problem as well. Thanks!

Comment: Another approach worth considering, if the set of prime(?) factors is especially rich, is to try factoring $z+1,z+2, \ldots$ into small factors (smooth numbers) until you find one susceptible to the kind of product representation you want.

Comment: You can convert this into a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Simply take the logarithm of all the numbers, i.e. $l_i=\log p_i$ and $L=\log z$. Now the problem is to find a minumum _sum_ of the $l_i$ that exceeds $L$. The more standard formulation is to find a maximum sum that does not exceed some goal value, but you can get that by subtracting it from $T=\sum_1^n l_i$. So find the subset of $l_i$ whose sum is closest but not greater than $T-L$.